# Spring - error connected to hibernate-validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I've got some problems with hibernate-validation and I don't know what is the reason. While initializing there are errors in the console. I want to use @PESEL adnotation from hibenrate-validation. I have read that I have to use new version of hibernate-validation but it causes the problem - I have tried to remove javax.validation or change version of hibernate-validation, but with no effect. Problem is still the same.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>admin-theme</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}/application.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>heroku</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>heroku</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@8c3619e: startup date [Sun Nov 26 06:58:24 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@8c3619e: startup date [Sun Nov 26 06:58:24 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/DefaultValidatorConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/DefaultValidatorConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ClockProvider
```

Comment: `javax.validation.ClockProvider` was added in validation-api version 2.0. Check dependency tree, what version do you have, and where that version came from. (BTW it is usually not recommended to override the versions given by the starters)

Answer (score 2):

i was also faced the same problem. This is due to incompatible of jar versions. I just updated the spring(5.1.5), spring-boot(2.1.6) & Spring data (1.94.4) version to latest stable version, issue got resolved